# How to retrieve the content of slurm script?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm

I submitted a job several days ago, and it is still running now. But I forget the content of that `script.sh` that day. And the `script.sh` has been deleted. Do you know how to recover the content of that script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With recent versions, you can retrieve the job script for your own jobs with

```
scontrol write batch_script <job_id> <optional_filename>
```

From the [man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html#OPT_write-batch_script):

> Write the batch script for a given job_id to a file or to stdout. The
> file will default to slurm-<job_id>.sh if the optional filename
> argument is not given. The script will be written to stdout if - is
> given instead of a filename. The batch script can only be retrieved by
> an admin or operator, or by the owner of the job.

On older versions, the `write batch_script` command does not exist, but you can get the script with

```
scontrol show -ddd job <job_id>
```

Comment: is it possible to retrive the output file defined via `#SBATCH --output=slurm.out`