# Is it possible to retrieve the output file defined via #SBATCH --output=slurm.out after deletion?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I accidentally deleted the output file of an `sbatch` job that is still running while deleting that of completed jobs.

I checked for `.local/share/Trash` and this folder does not even exist. Any chance I could retrieve this file using `sbatch` commands?

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677339/how-to-retrieve-the-content-of-slurm-script) as a comment, but no answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fortunate enough for the process to still be running, you can try the suggestions described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/283102/how-to-recover-deleted-file-if-it-is-still-opened-by-some-process).

On an NFS server, there might be a file in the same directory named something like `.nfs000000000e5dd56400042e84`. If so, you can use `tail -f` to recopy it to another file. This file will disappear as soon os the job terminates.

On a local filesystem, you will need to SSH to the compute node, and look into `/proc/<PID of process>/fd` for the file descriptor of the deleted file. As above, you can use `tail -f` to recopy it to another file. This file will disappear as soon os the job terminates.

Comment: Not fortunate to find the file using any of the suggestions. Process was still running but no trace of file in `/proc/<PID of process>/fd`.